# JavaScript FileReader empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms, filereader

My english is not good, but I will try to explain the problem. I'm trying to load multiple images in an asp.net webforms application, but when I'm loading the files the first image doesn't load. Look at the following code:

```
$('#loadImg').change(function () {

    for (var i = 0; i <= this.files.length; i++) {
        if (this && this.files[i]) {

            var reader = new FileReader(), valor;
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[i]);
            reader.onload = function () {
                valor = reader.result
            };

            var obj = new Object();
            obj.Objn = i;
            obj.Name = this.files[i].name;
            obj.Tipo = this.files[i].type;
            obj.Peso = this.files[i].size;
            obj.Obji = valor;                      

            var params = JSON.stringify(obj);
            if (IsValid(obj.Tipo)) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: uri1,
                    data: params,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.d) {
                            $('#objimg').attr('src', obj.Obji);
                        }
                    },
                    async: false,
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
                        alert("Error al cargar la imagen");
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    function IsValid(iTipo) {
        switch (iTipo) {
            case 'image/png': case 'image/gif': case 'image/jpeg': case 'image/pjpeg':
                return true; break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a list of the file names?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example regarding `reader.result` in `reader.onload` and `obj.Obji` in `success` (you don’t get the same `reader` or `obj`). Also, don’t check `if (this)`, that’s pointless after accessing `this.files` in the loop.

Comment: Yes i have a list of images